# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 Encrypted

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, encryption

So, maybe this is an obscure and stupid question to ask here, but, in my case, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 are not playing nicely at all.

Because I wanted to encrypt my laptop, I decided to `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda` my hard drive (1.5TB, took 1 day 4 hours to do). After that, I inserted a Windows 10 USB to install and during that install, I created 2 partitions, 750GB for NTFS and 750GB of unallocated space. Windows was installed, and I used BitLocker to encrypt with AES-256 setting without TPM but just a really long passphrase (Group Policy). That worked.

I then proceeded to install Ubuntu with a Live USB, but what happened was when I went into the boot options for the BIOS, the USB was listed under UEFI boot (oh, no, I deliberately disabled that crap because I knew it would cause problems). OK, I selected it, and booted into Ubuntu, and I created a small 500MB partition for `/boot`, and then used the remaining space for physical encryption on EXT4 file system. The Ubuntu installer asked me if I wanted to force UEFI, I selected "no", Ubuntu was installed, upon reboot, GRUB does not show Windows as an option (well, why is that? I saw that there was an option at the installer to "install alongside Windows 10", that meant that Ubuntu recognized the existence of Windows on my computer despite it being encrypted).

Before I wiped my hard drive, I backed up packages and restored them according to the accepted answer found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/243387/how-can-i-backup-my-programs-applications-so-that-after-i-reinstall-a-new-one. After the restoration, I was asked to reboot, and now, GRUB no longer recognizes Ubuntu, but Windows reappeared! What is going on? Are boot files being overwritten again and again without me even realizing it? How do I force the boot loader to recognize the existence of both systems and give me an option to boot into either one?

Comment: Ubuntu supports UEFI without a problem.  If you installed Windows on a GPT partition then you have to use UEFI mode, if you enable Legacy/CSM at this point, Windows will not boot.  How you dual boot Windows and Ubuntu in UEFI mode is a trivial task.  You have to repair the boot loader in order to have it see both operating systems, but that is true, no matter what.

Comment: have you run sudo update-grub ?

Comment: @Ramhound I installed Windows first, so how is it possible that I used GPT type partitions? I used the Windows Installation USB to partition the hard drive.

Comment: @Blaine No, but from what I read, you have to specify where Ubuntu was installed if you do `sudo update-grub` from a Live USB, you will have to specify which partition Ubuntu was installed on. How do I do that without erasing the Windows entry on GRUB?

Comment: @user2213307 - If you machine supports UEFI, in most configurations, by default your device is booted in UEFI mode and Windows uses GPT partitions.  Screenshots might explain what the disk looks like.